# Merge parquet file on standalone spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a simple way how to save `DataFrame` into a *single* `parquet` file or merge the directory containing metadata and parts of this `parquet` file produced by `sqlContext.saveAsParquetFile()` into a *single* file stored on NFS without using HDFS and hadoop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save only one file, rather than many, you can call `coalesce(1)` / `repartition(1)` on the RDD/Dataframe before the data is saved.

If you already have a directory with small files, you could create a Compacter process which would read in the exiting files and save them to one new file.  E.g.

```
val rows = parquetFile(...).coalesce(1)
rows.saveAsParquetFile(...)
```

You can store to a local file system using saveAsParquetFile.  e.g.

```
rows.saveAsParquetFile("/tmp/onefile/")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this method to compress parquet files using snappy format with Spark 1.6.1. I used overwrite so that I could repeat the process if needed. Here is the code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

object CompressApp {
  val serverPort = "hdfs://myserver:8020/"
  val inputUri = serverPort + "input"
  val outputUri = serverPort + "output"

  val config = new SparkConf()
           .setAppName("compress-app")
           .setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(config)
  val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
  sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")  
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Compressing Parquet...")
    val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputUri).coalesce(1)
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputUri)
    println("Done.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce(N)` has saved me so far. 
If your table is partitioned, then use `repartition("partition key")` as well.